# Connecting to Jenkins from Cruise Control CCTray using HTTPS

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, cctray

Does anyone know how to get Cruise Control's CCTray to connect to a Jenkins Https CI Server instance running on Openshift? The URL I want to connect to is in the form : https://jenkins-rhcloud.com/cc.xml

I have read the responses here ([using CCtray with Jenkins, while security enabled (using HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720277/using-cctray-with-jenkins-while-security-enabled-using-https))  about adding a transport extension to CCTray and have tried building and deploying jenkins transport dll as per the instructions. I built it in visual studio 2012 express and deployed to c:\program files\cctray\extensions and restarted cctay (version 1.8), but on restart it doesn't allow the jenkins plugin to be selected in the transport extension drop down? CCtray doesn't seem to know the trasport extension exists even though its deployed in the place according to the instructions! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ok I figured it out! What you have to do is build the jenkins transport in 32 bit mode using Visual Studio 2012 (all though with some modifications I also got it to work on VS 2008). If this still doesn't work, get the source code of CCNet from github and compile the CCTray project also in 32 bit mode and then insert jenkins plugin into the plugin into the extensions folder of the newly build exe. This will fix the issue.  If it doesn't the debugger will show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

From experience (and having just got this working!) the .net version for the JenkinsTransport.DLL build cannot be of a higher version than the CCTray install.

CCTray tries to load all DLLs in \extension and swallows any exception arising. A .net 3.5 built of JenkinsTransport.DLL doesn't work (not selectable) with CCTray 1.8.0.0 but does work against CCTray 1.8.4.0.